# How do I subtract an RDD[(Key,Object)] from another one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to change the format of my data, from RDD(Label:String,(ID:String,Data:Array[Double])) to an RDD Object with the label, id and data as components.
But when I print my RDD consecutively twice, the references of objects change :

```
class Data_Object(private val id:String, private var vector:Vector) extends Serializable {
var label = ""
...
}

First print 
(1,ms3.Data_Object@35062c11)
(2,ms3.Data_Object@25789aa9)

Second print
(2,ms3.Data_Object@6bf5d886)
(1,ms3.Data_Object@a4eb65)
```

I think that explains why the `subtract` method doesn't work. So can I use `subtract` with objects as values, or do I return to my classic model ?

Comment: How is your `Data_Object`class defined? You probably want to make it a case class so that the `toString` and `equals` methods are auto-generated for you...

Comment: Also, how are you printing? `rdd.foreach(println)`?

Comment: Yes i use rdd.foreach(println)

Comment: you're probably not overriding `hashCode` and `equals` on your `DataObject` class. As DNA mentions, use a case class. Also note that mutable data objects are discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you specify otherwise, objects in Scala (and Java) are compared using reference equality (i.e. their memory address). They are also printed out according to this address, hence the `Data_Object@6bf5d886` and so on.

Using reference equality means that two `Data_Object` instances with identical properties will NOT compare as equal unless they are exactly the same object. Also, their references will change from one run to the next.

Particularly in a distributed system like Spark, this is no good - we need to be able to tell whether two objects in two *different* JVMs are the same or not, according to their properties. Until this is fixed, RDD operations like `subtract` will not give the results you expect.

Fortunately, this is usually easy to fix in Scala/Spark - define your class as a [case class](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html). This automatically generates `equals` and `hashcode` and `toString` methods derived from all of the properties of the class. For example:

```
case class Data_Object(id:String, label:String, vector:Vector)
```

If you want to compare your objects according to only *some* of the properties, you'll have to define your own `equals` and `hashcode` methods, though. See [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/object-equality.html), for example.